# Why SWIG needs to generate manifest file with mt.exe?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, manifest, swig

I'm testing swig, and I found that SWIG's vcxproj file runs the mt.exe to generate the manifest file.

```
swig -c++ -csharp example.i
CL.exe ... -> compile the c++ source
link.exe ... -> generate dll
mt.exe ...
Csc.exe ...
```

What is this for? I skipped the mt.exe, but it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Very Big Deal in versions of VS prior to 2010.  mt.exe embeds the auto-generated manifest in the executable image, important to get the DLL dependencies that are stored in the Windows side-by-side cache listed.  Not much of a big deal anymore, it only embeds an "I'm compatible with Vista" manifest now.  The side-by-side cache was rather a big headache and abandoned for VS2010.

You ought to check the .manifest file in the build directory and make sure nothing important is in it.  Like the common dialogs version 6 entry that enables visual styles.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with SWIG, but with how Visual C++ generates it's binary output.

The [mt.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not *generate* a manifest file, it *embeds* the info from the manifest file that is already there (I think the linker would have created it) into the output DLL. Without this, the output DLL may only work while the manifest file resides along the DLL in the same directory.

(Note: I never really bothered to dig deeper regarding manifests, what info is exactly in there and if all the info in there is needed all the time, but since it's just all done automatically when you create an exe or dll in VC++ one shouldn't immediately need to bother unless something's not working :-)